# Am I solving this question correctly?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

How can I evaluate the following term:
$$\left((\{a,b\}\cup\{b,a\})\times(\{b,a\}\cap\{a,b\})\right)\setminus
\left((\{b,a\}\setminus\{a,b\})\cup(\{a,b\}\times\{b,a\})\right)$$

You can see the notes to my approach in this picture. Am I solving it correctly?
[image]

Comment: What is the question? Shall you evaluate the term in the first two lines?

Comment: computing the terms in the first two line

Comment: Also, for sets holds $\{a,b\}=\{b,a\}$ which makes your term really redundant — are you sure you wrote everything down correctly? which is the source of this assignment?

Comment: I made some minor mistakes http://imgur.com/cFwfrLh

Comment: Then please edit your question adding the correct content!

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Apart from tat, the things you tried do not really make sense in terms of mathematical formulation. What were you trying to do? And what should these diagrams mean?
You seem to be confusing a lot of things.

Comment: This is the way my professor taught me, to do the Cartesian product of sets. I had to use this "tree". He wants us to answer these questions using the ways he taught us so yea... Basically I have to use "his method" to solve it.

Comment: Doing is not necessary. One does not even _need_ to calculate the cartesian product, as you can see in my answer. And as mentioned, using $\{a,b\}$ and $\{b,a\}$ in the same term is redundant.

Comment: By the way, the reason your question got voted down is mainly because its main content is included in a photo, which is considered to be bad formatting and disliked by the community. This does not mean that your question was of bad quality!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under the assumption that you wrote the term down correctly:

$$
\begin{align}
&\left((\{a,b\}\cup\{b,a\})\times(\{b,a\}\cap\{a,b\})\right)\setminus
\left((\{b,a\}\setminus\{a,b\})\cup(\{a,b\}\times\{b,a\})\right)\\
&= \left((\{a,b\}\cup\{a,b\})\times(\{a,b\}\cap\{a,b\})\right)\setminus
\left(\emptyset\cup(\{a,b\}\times\{a,b\})\right)\\
&= \left(\{a,b\}\times\{a,b\}\right)\setminus
\left(\{a,b\}\times\{a,b\}\right)\\
&= \emptyset
\end{align}
$$
I am meanly using the folloving theorems:
$$\{a,b\}=\{b,a\}$$
$$A\cup A=A=A\cap A$$
$$A\setminus A = \emptyset$$

**EDIT:**
If you really *need* to calculate the product, just do so in the last step:
$$\begin{align}
&(\{a,b\}\times\{a,b\})\setminus(\{a,b\}\times\{a,b\})\\
&= \{(a, a),(a,b),(b,a),(b,b)\}\setminus\{(a, a),(a,b),(b,a),(b,b)\}\\
&=\{\}
\end{align}$$

**LATER EDIT:**
As I understood what you did in the photo, I can say that your approach is correct except one little thing:
$$\{\}\cup\{a,b,\cdots\}\neq\{\{\},a,b,\cdots\}$$
but rather $$\{\}\cup A=A$$
For all sets A. You confused this with
$$\{\{\}\}\cup\{a,b,\cdots\}=\{\{\},a,b,\cdots\}$$

Which is a mistake that often occurs.

Comment: would that answer be equivalent to a a blank set { }

Comment: $\emptyset=\{\}$, just another symbol for the same thing.

Comment: @melancholyx3 not sure if you will notice — I added a few things in an edit. There is also one on your own question.

Comment: so {}∪{a,b,⋯} would equal to {a,b,...}? I think I understand what you're trying to say now.

Comment: Exactly — the empty sets contains zero elements, and thus there are no elements added by toking the union. But $\{\{\}\}$ contains _one_ element (even if it's onvy the empty set), which is thus added to the other set.

Comment: got it! thanks! I sort of have another question, should I make a new post or can I reply here?

Comment: Open another question. Comments should be short and on-topic regarding the actual question/answer. Or, even better, search if your question already has an answer on this site.